# How to use substitution string for owner when running installations scripts in APEX Application?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want to use the `#OWNER#` or the `#FLOW_OWNER#` variable in a supporting object installation script on a APEX application but is not working.

script:

```
insert into #FLOW_OWNER#.my_app_table (id,name) values (1,'Tom');
```

error:

> ORA-00911: invalid character

I have an Apex application on Apex 4.2.6. Apex has a supporting objects installation scripts features, that are scripts that will be executed after the application install on an Apex environment. I want my script to insert a user in the access control table. But that application will be deployed on different environments, with different schema owners. So I want to use the APEX variables to make sure it gets the right schema on this post installation script.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for my case using **apex_util.get_default_schema()** and **execute immediate**, that is what I did:

```
BEGIN 
execute immediate 'insert into '||apex_util.get_default_schema()||'.my_app_table (id,name) values (1,''Tom'')'; 
END;
```